# Display Cyrillic and special characters in dp:serialize (DataPower)

Tags: xslt, serialization, soap, message, ibm-datapower

I want to display a whole SOAP message using XSL. I know that message is in `var://context/INPUT` variable and to display a whole message I use serialization `<dp:serialize select="dp:variable('var://context/INPUT')"/>` (`dp` is for IBM DataPower variables).

But this way, if message contains characters like `ćčš` or `љњшђж` they are displayed like `#1084;&#1080` and so on. `disable-output-escaping = "yes"` doesn't work with serialization.

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify where do you want to display the SOAP message? If you could throw some more lights into what do you want to achieve may be I can help? - Ajitabh

Comment: disable-output-escaping is not property of dp:serialize.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the message is XML you can't really do anything about it as DataPower will escape those characters, else risking "destroying" the message if there is a character code conversion.
You would have to convert the message into a binaryNode to get round that issue I am afraid.